# how can i capture src in xml by using cssSelector or Xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, css-selectors, css

how can i capture src in following xml by using cssSelector or Xpath ?

```
<INPUT src="/TelsimGlobal/Menu/image3.gif" type=image>
```

i tried to execute following ones but always faced with "Unable to find element" error. any suggestion ?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/TelsimGlobal/Menu/image3.gif']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[src]"));                                
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[src='/TelsimGlobal/Menu/image3.gif']"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an image (IMG) or a link (A) tag, it is a INPUT tag:

```
By.xpath("//input[@src='/TelsimGlobal/Menu/image3.gif']")
```

Comment: @santino87 Upvote or accept the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of future readers. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote